# how to get ckeditor value in laravel controler

Tags: ckeditor

I have a ckeditor in my form, which in the store method of the controller, request returns a null value for it.

```
<div id="editor" style="font-size: medium;">
<p>Write Your task Description</p>
</div>
<div id="toolbar-container"></div>
<textarea style='display:none;' name='taskDsc' id='taskDsc' ></textarea>
<script>
     DecoupledEditor
     .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ),
     {
          language:{
           ui:'fa',content:'fa'
           }
     }
          )
    .then( editor => {
                       const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector( '#toolbar-container' );
                       toolbarContainer.appendChild( editor.ui.view.toolbar.element );
                      } )
      .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
            } );
</script>
 <script>
     $(document).on('submit','.submit',function(){
      html = $("#editor").html()
      $("#taskDsc").val(html)
      })
</script>
```

in controller:

```
public function store(taskRequestStore $request)
{
         dd($request);
}
```

but request value for taskDsc is null.

```
"taskDsc" => null
```

Where have I done the work wrongly or incompletely? what's the solution?

Comment: The hidden textarea need to inside the form tags

Comment: I saw the answer and changed my code accordingly but I still get null value

Comment: use the second answer where you create the formData from scratch if the ckeditor data is all you need. Otherwise put your hidden textArea inside the form tags